# No matching function for call to std::map

Tags: c++

При исполнении данной функции происходит ошибка:

> ```
> no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>,
> char>::insert(std::pair<std::basic_string<char>,
> std::basic_string<char> >)'
> ```

Сам код:

```
void inital() {
    char buff[100];
    ifstream fin("cmd.txt");
    int strnum = 0;
    char end[] = "#STOP";
    map <string, char> cmd;
    while(strcmp(buff, end) != 0) {
    std::cmatch result;
    std::regex my_regex("^PRG (.+) CMD ([a-z][0-9]+)$");
    if (std::regex_match(buff, result, my_regex ) ) {
    cmd.insert(make_pair(result[2].str(),result[1].str()));
    }
    fin.getline(buff, 100);
    strnum++;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну дык всё правильно, читайте сообщения компилятора, он фигню не говорит.

```
map <string, char> cmd;
cmd.insert(make_pair(result[2].str(),result[1].str()));
```

У вас тип char а вы туда строку передаёте. Пишите уже `result[1].str()[0]` или как-то так.